# How to get Request.IsAuthenticated to return false?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I would like to sign a user out and also have the `Request.IsAuthenticated` property return false.

I am not using FormsAuthentication but the default CookieAuthentication available in Katana.

When a user's session expires, I want to sign him out, so I have an action filter like so:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;

    if (session.IsNewSession || session["UserId"] == null)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = BusinessObjects.Constants.SessionExpiredJsonResult };
            }
            else
            {
                var authenticationManager = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

                if (authenticationManager != null)
                {
                    authenticationManager.SignOut();

                    Trace.TraceInformation(filterContext.HttpContext.User == null ? "User is null" : "User is not null");
                    Trace.TraceInformation(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity == null ? "User.Identity is null" : "User.Identity is not null");
                    Trace.TraceInformation(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
                }

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/SessionExpired.cshtml" };
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

The **SessionExpired** view loads up nicely, but it has a partial view that it renders, which has the following code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink((string)(Session["FullName"] ?? User.Identity.Name), "Index", controllerName })
        </li>

        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign up", "Signup", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
        </li>
    </ul>

}
```

When this partial view executes, even though the `HttpSessionState` and the `HttpSessionBase` objects are null, the `Request.IsAuthenticated` property returns true. As a result, I do see the user as being still logged in even though his session has expired and I even have called `authenticationManager.SignOut()` previously.

How do I get the user's identity information to disappear and consequently have the `Request.IsAuthenticated` property to return false?

Comment: why don't you just call `authenticationManager.SignOut();` in a "logOut" action? The `Request.IsAuthenticated` will update in the next request

Comment: I've already done that. Leaving all else, the only option for me is to have the user come back again. In other words, to not return a view result directly from this same request but instead send him a redirect result. That's what I have done for now to make things work so that the next time around when he comes, the request needs authentication again.

Comment: yeah, that is what I do. `authenticationManager.SignOut(); return RedirectToAction("SignIn");`. Is there a problem in this approach?

Comment: No, that's what I am going to do. I was thinking of avoiding that one redirect.

Comment: I believe that it's not possible to update the `Request.IsAuthenticated` without a redirect

Comment: I think you may be right.